# axios post Login CORS Error "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, postman

I use postman test Login is OK,but I use React axios post test Login is CORS Error.

errorCode:Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:117:1)

```
./app.js

import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
    const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const axiosLogin = () => {
        axios
            .post("https://mycosim.ntunhs.edu.tw/login", {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
                username: username,
                password: password,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input
                type="text"
                value={username}
                onChange={(event) => setUserName(event.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your name"
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                value={password}
                onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter your password"
            />
            <button onClick={() => axiosLogin()}>Submit</button>
            {username}/{password}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Error image
[image: Network1]

[image: Network2]

PostMan View

[image: PostMan View1]
[image: PostMan View2]

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to different server if the server allow [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Postman simply doesn't care about CORS headers

You need to enable cors from server

Answer (score -1):

Just add:
mode: ‘no-cors’
before headers.